# What are mutator genes which cause copying errors in other genes?

Tags: evolution, gene-expression

Reading Dawkins' book "The Selfish Gene," I came across this line: "There are even genes--called mutators--that manipulate the rates of copying errors in other genes." (The context is his argument that such a gene is looking out for its best interest by killing off the competition.)

What are these "mutator" genes, and how do they function?

Answer (score 2):

Most obvious examples are the genes directly involved in [DNA mismatch repair (MMR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_mismatch_repair) such as [mutS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSH2), [mutL](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P23367), [mutH](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P06722), MLH1 and MLH2.